# Ai: How do I apply a layer's layer style (eg shadow) only to the object or group below it?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, layers, layer-style

So if I want the shadow for the blue hat to only fall on the face, and not blur out onto the background etc, is there any simple-ish way to do this?

[image]

Comment: Your image is behind a log in and will not display. You'll need to correct that.

Comment: Sorry Scott! Hope it works now.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use a Clipping mask. Make a new shape and frame the shadow you want to keep. Select object with shadow and "the frame" shape (on top). Then hit Cmd + 7

[image: Shadow, clippingmask]